# Regex: searching for exactly 3 capital letters

Tags: regex

I am using https://pythex.org/ to test the following:

I want to search the test string below, select all consecutive characters that have exactly three capital letters.

Test string: `bcAc BBGFeQFFJaaBx EBBcDDD`

`[A-Z]{3}` returns all groups of 3 uppercase characters and even those with 4 inside. I have tried to force only 3 capitals using `^[A-Z]{3}$` but this does not work either.

In the above string I only want `EBB` and `DDD` to be matched.

Comment: only adding why `^[A-Z]{3}$` not works, it means that look for string which from start of line `(character ^)` to end of line `(character $)` contains exactly 3 uppercase characters, lines like `DDD` or `EBB` would works but not your test string or `DDe` or `DDDD` wouldn't  or other combinations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use negative lookarounds:

```
[A-Z]{3}(?<![A-Z]{4})(?![A-Z])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/exmakI/1)

Comment: I have now modified this to search for three consecutive uppercase characters that are the same followed by a lowercase character: ([A-Z])\1\1(?<![A-Z]{4})(?![A-Z])([a-z]). This worked but when I then wanted to end it with three more characters eg AAAbCCC I tried the following which did not work ([A-Z])\1\1(?<![A-Z]{4})(?![A-Z])([a-z])([A-Z])\1\1(?<![A-Z]{4})(?![A-Z]). There is something that I am not understanding

Comment: You didn't cook the right regex what you need is `(?:[A-Z]){3}(?<![A-Z]{4})[a-z](?:[A-Z]){3}(?![A-Z])` @ABasel

Comment: Thanks for that. I needed to group (a-z) to get it to work in my code i.e. (?:[A-Z]){3}(?<![A-Z]{4})([a-z])(?:[A-Z]){3}(?![A-Z]). This works for any 3 letter combination of uppercase letters but how would I change this if I wanted to check for three consecutive uppercase letters that were the same e.g. AAAfKKK or ZZZsDDD?

Comment: Please check this [**`([A-Z])\1\1(?<![A-Z]{4})[a-z]([A-Z])\2\2(?![A-Z])`**](https://regex101.com/r/tyqiTD/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I used negative lookbehinds and lookaheads to make sure that there were no capital letters in front of or behind the three-letter bits.

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only three capital letters to be matched (such as `EBB` or `DDD`) to be matched, then think about which character comes ***before*** or ***after*** the group of 3 capital letters.

`[^A-Z]` means "exactly one character which is **not** a capital letter."

Thus the following two things are equivalent:

| Regex | English |
| --- | --- |
| `[^A-Z][A-Z]{3}[^A-Z]` | (1) one thing which is not a capital letter (2) three capital letters (3) one thing which is not a capital letter |

I apologize for the formatting of the numbered list inside of the table. stackoverflow supports numbered lists outside of tables, but not inside of tables. Also, I cannot insert manual line-break inside of a stackoverflow table.

Anyway, our regular expression is still not ideal.

| GENERAL PROBLEM | EXAMPLE OF PROBLEM |
| --- | --- |
| The non-capital letters are captured. | If you search inside of the string `xxxxxbAAAbxxxxx` then output might contain `bAAAb` instead of `AAA` |
| The begining of a string and end of string pose a problem | If you search inside of `AAAxxxxBBBxxx` we will find `BBB` but not `AAA` |

One solution is the following:

```
(?:^|[^A-Z])([A-Z]{3})(?:[^A-Z]|$)
```

Consider the text `John Doe.......303-159-8712......jdoe@gmail.com.......Contractor`

- We want to ***delete*** the dots (`...`).
- We want to ***keep*** `John Doe` and `303-159-8712` etc...

#### What are capturing groups?

- A caputuring group labels text as "keep me"
- A non-capturing group marks text as "delete me"

| Regex | English |
| --- | --- |
| `|` | The vertical pipe character is similar to the English word "`or` |
| `^` | beginning (left end) of the text |
| `$` | end of the text (right-most end of the string) |
| `[A-Z]` | One capital letter from A through Z |
| `[^A-Z]` | One character other than a letter from A through Z |
| `[^A-Z]|$` | One character other than a letter from A through Z or the end of the text |
| `^|[^A-Z]` | beginning of string |
| `(?:[^A-Z]|$)` | The question-mark-colon (`?:`) says that this is a chunk of text we want to delete/ignore. The chunk of text contains only one thing. This only thing is either the end of the line or one character other than a capital letter. |

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/1US8Zj/1)